# Styles is not loading in my laravel program

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have a view which I'm returning in my `AdminController` which goes in this syntax.

```
public function create_booking(){
  $set_admin = SettingAdmin::orderBy('id')->first();
  return view('layouts\quickbookingmodal')->with('set_admin', $set_admin);
}
```

In HTML this is what im returning, this basically is a pop menu, where the admin user can fill a booking.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class=row>
      <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-content">

              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Quick Booking</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  @isset($error_msg)
                    @foreach ($error_msg as $error)
                        <li class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                  @endisset
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="placeid" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Place ID') }}: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="place_id" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="placeid" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Arrival day') }}: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="container11">
                          <div class="t-datepicker">
                            <span id="tdatepik" class="t-check-in"></span>
                            <input id="searchdate_numberofdays" type="number" name="no_of_day" placeholder="{{ __('Number of days') }}: 1">
                            @isset($maparray['err_msg'])
                              <span id="errormsg_txt" style="color:red;"> {{ __('You can book maximum') }} {{ $maparray["set_admin"]->max_no_days }} {{ __('days') }}.</span><br>
                            @endisset
                            <span id="errormsg_txt" style="color:red;display:none;"> {{ __('Arrival day is not selected') }}. </span><br>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="fullname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Full Name') }}: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_fullname" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Email address') }}: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user_email" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Phone') }}: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="user_phone" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="geust" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Number of adults') }}[1-4]: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control booking_inp_textbox_style" id="numberofguest" name="numberofguest" onchange="addFieldsadmin(this.value);">
                          <option value="0" active>1</option>
                          <option value="1">2</option>
                          <option value="2">3</option>
                          <option value="3">4</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="babies" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Number of babies') }}[1-3]: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control booking_inp_textbox_style" id="numberofbabies" name="numberofbabies" onchange="addFieldsadmin2(this.value);">
                          <option value="0" active>0</option>
                          <option id="hidden_op_style1" value="1">1</option>
                          <option id="hidden_op_style2" value="2">2</option>
                          <option id="hidden_op_style3" value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="containerinput">
                    {{-- dynamic input surname using javascript --}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="containerinput2">
                    {{-- dynamic input surname using javascript --}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="promo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Promo Code') }}: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_promo">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="book" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Booked By') }}: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</label>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  @if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin')
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="Amount" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Payment Type') }}: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="radio" name="user_payment_type" value="Entrance">
                        <label for="Entrance" class="booking_payment_type_style">{{ __('Entrance (Cash)') }}</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="radio" name="user_payment_type" value="Admin" checked>
                        <label for="Entrance" class="booking_payment_type_style">{{ __('Admin (Free)') }}</label><br>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  @else
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="promo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Payment Type') }}: </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="radio" name="user_payment_type" value="Entrance" checked>
                        <label for="Entrance" class="booking_payment_type_style">{{ __('Entrance (Cash)') }}</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  @endif



              </div>

              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var today = new Date();
tomorrow = new Date(today);
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 60);
var date = tomorrow.getFullYear()+'-'+(tomorrow.getMonth()+1)+'-'+tomorrow.getDate();
   $(document).ready(function(){
      // Call global the function

      $('.t-datepicker').tDatePicker({
        // options here

        titleDateRange :'{{ __('day') }}',
        titleDateRanges:'{{ __('days') }}',
        titleToday     :'{{ __('Today') }}',
        limitDateRanges    :'{{ $set_admin->max_no_days+1 }}',
        titleCheckIn   :'{{ __('Check In') }}',
        titleCheckOut  :'{{ __('Check Out') }}',
        numCalendar : 1,
        endDate: date,
        nextDayHighlighted   :false,
        toDayHighlighted     :true,
        toDayShowTitle       :true,
        autoClose: true,
        dateRangesHover: false,

      });
    });

    // $('.t-datepicker').tDatePicker('setEndDate','2020-07-28');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

@isset($error_msg)
  @if (count($error_msg) > 0)
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  @endif
@endisset

</script>
```

But anytime i load the page, it does not load it as a popup just static HTML. However i have the same popup in this page called dashboard, which when clicked shows the popup perfectly with all the styles. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
@extends('layouts.adminmaster')

@section('section')
  <div class="container paddingTop20">
    <h1>Negombo Admin Panel</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <span class="dashboardcardstyle">{{ __('Quick Booking') }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-success dashboardcardbodystyle2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{ __('Book Now') }}</button></center>
            @include('layouts.quickbookingmodal')
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <span class="dashboardcardstyle">Total Places</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <center><span class="dashboardcardbodystyle">{{ $numberofplace }}</span></center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <span class="dashboardcardstyle">Total Bookings</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <center><span class="dashboardcardbodystyle">{{ $numberofbookings }}</span></center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
          @include('layouts.recentactivaty')
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">

      </div>
    </div>


    {{-- second row of dashboard --}}
    <div class="row paddingTop20">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        @if (Auth::user()->role== "admin")
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary">
              <span class="dashboardcardstyle">Total Earnings</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">

            <table style="width:100%" align="center" class="table-hover">
              <tr>
                <td><strong>From Entrance: </strong></td>
                <td>{{ $earningEntrance }} <i class="fa fa-eur" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>From {{ __('Agreements') }}: </strong></td>
                <td>{{ $earningAgr }} <i class="fa fa-eur" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>From Paypal: </strong></td>
                <td>{{ $earningPaypal }} <i class="fa fa-eur" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>From Stripe: </strong></td>
                <td> {{ $earningStripe }} <i class="fa fa-eur" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>From Credit Card: </strong></td>
                <td>{{ $earningcard }} <i class="fa fa-eur" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
              {{-- <center><span class="dashboardcardbodystyle">{{ $numberofbookings }}</span></center> --}}
            </div>
          </div>
        @else
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary">
              <span class="dashboardcardstyle">Server Time</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <center><span>{{ date("d M, Y") }}</span></center>
              <center><span class="dashboardcardbodystyle">{{ date("h:i:s A") }}</span></center>
            </div>
          </div>
        @endif
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <span class="dashboardcardstyle">{{ __('Total') }} {{ __('Agreements') }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <center><span class="dashboardcardbodystyle">{{ $numberofAggr }}</span></center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header bg-primary">
            <span class="dashboardcardstyle">Total Entrance</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <center><span class="dashboardcardbodystyle">{{ $numberofEntrance }}</span></center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{-- second row of dashboard --}}
  </div>
@endsection
```

This is how the popup is supposed to look like.

[image]

But this is how it looks

[image]

This is what i get when i add the @extends('layouts.adminmaster') and @section('section')

[image]

Comment: Can you share all the code of quickbookingmodal view?

Comment: Are you including `@extends('layouts.adminmaster')` and `@section('section')` on that modal view?

Comment: The code attached above includes all the code of the quickbookingmodal view. And no i'm not including those 2 as when i include them in the quickbookingmodal, it renders only the administrator page.

Comment: I edited the post above to show you the view i get once i add the '@extends('layouts.adminmaster') and and @section('section')

Comment: Try adding your style links directly in that modal view

Comment: Tried doing that now, the format changed a bit, but still does not look like how it is intedned on doing :(

Comment: Did you clear the data of the browser?

Comment: The problem has all to do with your Bootstrap stylesheet link.. Somehow you must figure it out why that view is not connecting to it.

Comment: Alright will do that, thanks for your time and help!